# Error: After Effects cannot open files in the “After Effects Project” format

Tags: finder, catalina, filesystem, adobe, macos

Not sure if this is an Adobe or Apple issue, or both.

When I try to open an After Effects file (`.aep`) or Premiere Project file (`.pproj`) from Finder, by double-clicking, or using "Open With", I get this error:

[image]

The only way to open the project is `File > Open Project...` from within Ae/Pr, which requires me to navigate to the containing folder from the Open dialog window. Opening from `File > Open Recent >` also works.

It's not a file-association issue; I've checked that.

Even dragging the `aep` on to the Ae icon (in Dock or app switcher) doesn’t work.

Sometimes restarting the computer will temporarily fix the issue.

A while back, I solved the issue without restarting by going to `System Preferences > Security > Full Disk Access > Enable After Effects`. But that isn't working anymore.

(macos Catalina)